# Parsing a list from a JSON like string in Kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin, parsing

I have a below String :

```
[{-600,0},{0,10},{100,20},{150,100},{400,10},{500,0}]
```

It look like that it's not a proper json.
I need to fetch each value i.e. -600, 0 ,10, 20 etc.. from this String.

Is it possible through Gson.parseJson() or I have to manage it manually?
How?
Any logic? Please guide..

Comment: If it really does just always look like that, it might even be easier to parse it manually. I doubt Gson would be able to parse it, but I might be wrong.

Comment: `How? Any logic?` you really want to ask for logic on splitting this ? considering you said this is a string, just remove `[`, `{` `}` `]` and then split on the `,` then you have an array of values, or is that not what you wanted ?

Comment: Ya I have to save -600,0 in one object, then 0,10 in another object. If I split it with "," after removing the { and [] } then, what I am getting is each seperate values. instead of bunch of values like -600,0 and 0,10 and 100,20.

Comment: @JaiminModi exactly, after removing that you will have something like -600,0,0,10,100,20 .... Then split that string with reference to comma (",") and you will get your desire result.

Comment: that still wouldn't matter, just loop over your array and build your own objects ? index 0 and 1 would be one object, 2 and 3 another, etc.

Comment: @a_local_nobody Would you able to do it please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might as well give up on treating it as "almost JSON" and parse it as a string - remove the `[]{}` characters and `split` on `,`:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val regex = """(\{|\}|\[|\])""".toRegex()

    val data = "[{-600,0},{0,10},{100,20},{150,100},{400,10},{500,0}]"

    regex.replace(data, "").split(",").also {
        println(it) // [-600, 0, 0, 10, 100, 20, 150, 100, 400, 10, 500, 0]
    }
}
```